# Calling a variable in a string (Hyperlink) - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, variables, discord.js

So basically in order to use discord hyperlink, I can't break the string to add the variable as I would too. I already tried to call it with $ and {} but it doesn't work.

```
   .addField('Shortcuts', $'[Profilo](https://twitter.com/{tweet.user.screen_name})')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which needs backticks and `${}` around the variable:

```js
.addField('Shortcuts', `[Profilo](https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name})`)
```

Comment: You have to use backticks, not single quotes. Either copy the code from my answer or [read up on how to type backticks](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows).